# What is the best way to use LazyColumn with itemsIndexed in PagingData this is deprecated

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging

What is the best way to use LazyColumn with itemsIndexed in PagingData this is deprecated
deprecated code:

```kotlin
val list = (state as State.Success).data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 50.dp)
        .border(4.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        .padding(padding)
) {
    itemsIndexed(list) {}
}
```

How would the new code look?

[SOLVED]

```kotlin
val list = (state as State.Success).data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    items(
        count = list.itemCount,
        key = list.itemKey(),
        contentType = list.itemContentType()
    ) { index ->
        val item = list[index]
    }
}
```